# What form element names break wordpress?

Tags: forms, 404-error

I know that `<input name="name">` will cause wp to bork and throw a 404.  It seems that 'year' is the same.  Does there exist a list of input names that wp doesnt like?

Comment: I just put `<input name="name">` into a post without any issues. What do you base this on?

Comment: I think you are talking about when you submit the form, right? There are a number or private and public [query vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) WordPress uses. Is this what you are refering to?

Comment: Yes, when you submit a form with an element named 'name' or 'year' or 'day', etc you'll get a 404. (maybe only sometimes) I found the answer while trying to respond to Rarst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely avoid the [public WordPress query vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables):

```
attachment
attachment_id
author
author_name
cat
category_name
comments_popup
day
error
feed
hour
hour
m
minute
monthnum
name
p
page_id
paged
pagename
post_parent
post_type
preview
second
static
subpost
subpost_id
tag
tag_id
tb
w
year
```

There's also this list of reserved terms, inexplicably located on the [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) page, with the ones above, plus some others:

```
attachment
attachment_id
author
author_name
calendar
cat
category
category__and
category__in
category__not_in
category_name
comments_per_page
comments_popup
customize_messenger_channel
customized
cpage
day
debug
error
exact
feed
hour
link_category
m
minute
monthnum
more
name
nav_menu
nonce
nopaging
offset
order
orderby
p
page
page_id
paged
pagename
pb
perm
post
post__in
post__not_in
post_format
post_mime_type
post_status
post_tag
post_type
posts
posts_per_archive_page
posts_per_page
preview
robots
s
search
second
sentence
showposts
static
subpost
subpost_id
tag
tag__and
tag__in
tag__not_in
tag_id
tag_slug__and
tag_slug__in
taxonomy
tb
term
theme
type
w
withcomments
withoutcomments
year
```

Answer (score 0):

Reserved Terms
Avoiding the following reserved terms is particularly important if you are passing the term through the $_GET or $_POST array. Doing so can cause WordPress to respond with a 404 error without any other hint or explanation.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms